# Reading Global Navigation in SharePoint from a Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, web-parts

Is it possible to read the Global Navigation of all the sub sites and display the items (links or category) from a Web Part that should be in a master page?

Don't forget that the global navigation can be edited in the settings, so I can't just loop on pages and sub sites. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the navigation using :
SPNavigationNodeCollection navNodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;